# Double precision function wp(S,wmav,ip)

Tags: fortran, simulation, spectrum

At this time I using Plato for compiling free IDE for Fortran.

My problem is about how to properly compile this code. It always gives an error code but whenever I search on google I find nothing.

This code is from Understanding luminance spectra and efficiency using wp and related function from Charles W Struck.

If there is somebody want to discuss about luminance spectra or theoretical things about this book I am open.

```
      options/g_float
      double precision function wp(S,wmav,ip)
C
C
C       finds one particular wp function, knowing its fundamental
C       arguments S,wmav, ip.
C
C
C       largest allowed ip is 70
C
C       eq. (4.45)
C
C
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H, O-P, R-Z), LOGICAL*4(Q)
      dimension pfact1(47),pfact2(24),pfact(71)
      equivalence (pfact(1),pfact1(1)),(pfact(48),pfact2(1))
      data pfactl/l.d000,1.d000,2.d000,6.d000,24.d000,l20.d000,720.d000,
     15040.d000,40320.d000,362880.d000,3.6288d006,3.99168d007,
     24.790016d008,6.2270208d009,8.71782912d010,1.307674368d012,
     32.0922789888d013,3.55687428096d014,6.402373705728000d+015,
     41.216451004088320d+017,2.432902008176640d+018,
     55.109094217170944d+019,1.124000727777608d+021,
     62.585201673888498d+022,6.204484017332395d+023,
     71.551121004333099d+025,4.032914611266057d+026,
     81.088886945041835d+028,3.048883446117139d+029,
     98.841761993739703d+030,2.652528598121911d+032,
     a8.222838654177925d+033,2.631308369336936d+035,
     b8.683317618811888d+036,2.952327990396042d+038,
     c1.033314796638615d+040,3.719933267899013d+041,
     d1.376375309122635d+043,5.230226174666011d+044,
     e2.039788208119744d+046,8.159152832478978d+047,
     f3.345252661316381d+049,1.405006117752880d+051,
     g6.041526306337384d+052,2.658271574788449d+054,
     h1.196222208654802d+056,5.502622159812090d+057/
      data pfact2/
     12.586232415111682d+059,1.241391559253608d+061,
     26.082818640342677d+062,3.041409320171339d+064,
     31.551118753287383d+066,8.065817517094390d+067,
     44.274883284060027d+069,2.308436973392415d+071,
     51.269640335365828d+073,7.109985878048638d+074,
     64.052691950487723d+076,
     72.350561331282880d+078,1.386831185456899d+080,
     88.320987112741393d+081,5.075802138772249d+083,
     93.146997326038795d+085,1.982608315404441d+087,
     a1.268869321858842d+089,8.247650592082473d+090,
     b5.443449390774432d+092,3.647111091818869d+094,
     c2.480035542436831d+096,1.711224524281413d+098,
     d1.197857166996989d+100/
      pr=dfloat(ip)
      ipr=ip
      if(ip.lt.0)then
        pr=-pr
        ipr=-ip
      end if
      boltz=wmav/(1.d000+wmav)
      boltzl=dlog(boltz)
      smav=S*wmav
      smplav=smav+S
      s2mp1=smav+smp1av
      if(s2mp1.le.235.d000)then
        bp=dexp(-s2mp1)*smplav**pr/pfact(ipr+1)
      else
        bp=dexp(dlog(s2mp1)+pr*dlog(smplav)-dlog(pfact(ipr+1)))
      end if
      bsum=1.d000
      blsum=0.d000
      blterm=1.d000
      wnum=smav*smp1av
      wdnom1=0.d000
      wdnom2=pr
      do 1 j=1,150
        wdnom1=wdnom1+1.d000
        wdnom2=wdnom2+1.d000
        bterm=wnum*blterm/(wdnom1*wdnom2)
        bsum=bsum+bterm
        if(bsum.eq.blsum)then
          wp=bsum*bp
          if(ip.lt.0)then
            if(pr*boltzl.le.200.d000)then
              wp=wp*(boltz**pr)
            else
              wp=0.d000
            end if
          end if
          return
        else
          blsum=bsum
          blterm=bterm
        end if
1     continue
      END
```

Error note :

```
F95(1) : error 201 - '(' expected after OPTIONS
F95(7) : error 609 - Expected '/' at end of DATA list
F95(8) : error 699 - Invalid character '.' at start of line
F95(8) : error 32 - Statement not recognised
F95(33) : warning 21 - Label 88 is declared, but not used
F95(7) : error 52 - Compilation abandoned
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour], read [ask] and foremost, show us your **complete error message** and the exact compilation command you use.

Comment: Do note that the first line `options/g_float` does not belong to Fortran. Also note that it is a function, not a complete program.

Comment: this is my Error note :
F95(1) : error 201 - '(' expected after OPTIONS
F95(7) : error 609 - Expected '/' at end of DATA list
F95(8) : error 699 - Invalid character '.' at start of line
F95(8) : error 32 - Statement not recognised
F95(33) : warning 21 - Label 88 is declared, but not used
F95(7) : error 52 - Compilation abandoned

Comment: what should I do for making it as a function?

Comment: As I said, the first line `options/g_float` does not belong to Fortran. Remove the fist line.

Comment: still have error, actually most of errors only at data pfact

Comment: I got it, thank you sir for your help.

Comment: Be careful when adjusting the lines. The first characters in the data lines `1`,`2`,`3`,...,`a`,`b`,`c`... are not part of the data, but are statement-continuation markers. They should be positioned in the 6th character column! So to be clear, the second line of the data block `pfactl` shows `15040.d000` but the value in the data is `5040.d000`

Comment: @VladimirF, I don't believe the column positions are wrong.

Comment: The values in the data are incorrect. There are values containing letters (`l` vs `1`) example:  `l.d000` instead of `1.d000` and `l20.d000` instead of `120.d000`

Comment: @kvantour That is quite possible, but the compiler certainly does not understand the data block. It is often very difficult to assess the column numbers here. And the message about the label 88 is suspicious.